# Vue CLI3 project npm run build doesn't produce a manifest.js file

Tags: webpack, vue-cli

I generated a default CLI3 VueJS app, ran 'npm install', then ran 'npm run build'. The dist folder only contains app.js and vendor.js files. (Yes, the file names contain random characters such as 'app.22467ja98.js' but I'm excluding that for simplicity)

All the documentation references a manifest.js file that should also be generated, but no such file is in the dist folder... Is this a webpack setting? If so, why is it not the CLI3 template default to produce the manifest.js, and how does one tell webpack to produce this file since the CLI3 paradigm is to not have a webpack.config.js file in the project?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it depends on the version of VueJs you are using (I am using 2.9.6) but you might want to try the following command to create your 'starter' project code.  This command uses the PWA project template in Vue:

```
vue init pwa [project_name]
```

An example might be:

```
vue init pwa myproj123
```

Note: the **manifest.json** file will be found under the project **static** folder after running the command

To check that you have the pwa template in your version of VueJs, you can run the following command to show the list of templates available to you:

```
vue list
```